# VBA: How do I allow filters to be turned on and off on a protected sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, filter, autofilter

I have the following piece of code, which removes filters and then re-applies them from selected cells:

```
Range("A10:AM10").Select

Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter
```

The problem I have is that when the sheet is protected and I try to run the code it errors, so is there a way of allowing filters to be turned on and off on a protected sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you?

It will depend on the setup of the protection. When you protect a worksheet, there is an option to allow filtering (AutoFilter).

If you're the one who's protecting the sheet, you can use any of the worksheet's **protect** method's parameters to set the protection options. Here are the protect method's parameters:

```
sheetName.Protect(Password, DrawingObjects, Contents, Scenarios, UserInterfaceOnly, AllowFormattingCells, AllowFormattingColumns, AllowFormattingRows, AllowInsertingColumns, AllowInsertingRows, AllowInsertingHyperlinks, AllowDeletingColumns, AllowDeletingRows, AllowSorting, AllowFiltering, AllowUsingPivotTables)
```

If you want to be able to implement filters only by code, then you can set the  UserInterfaceOnly parameter to TRUE. The protection will block only the users changes. Code changes will be fully allowed.

```
sheetName.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Or, if you want to allow users to filter the contents of the worksheet from the interface, just set the AllowFiltering parameter to TRUE as well as the UserInterfaceOnly parameter.

```
sheetName.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

Your code should work with both options.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without protecting the sheet through code? I.e. just protecting it through Excel's "Protect Sheet" button?

Comment: Hi @BenSmith. Yes, there is. On the "Protect Sheet" dialog there is a list of protection options. One of them is "Use AutoFilter" (I'm using Excel 2013. I don't remember if the name is different on earlier versions of Excel. But its there!). Just mark that checkbox and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the UserInterfaceOnly setting only is valid during the time the file is open after the setting is done. Closing the file and then reopening it and trying to set Autofilter by vba results in error 400. My solution was to unprotect and then protect the sheet again before setting autofilter.